# .net - Using Class as one parameter

Tags: vb.net, class, properties, parameters

I have a class with several properties.

```
Public Class test
    Public Property a As String
    Public Property b As String
    Public Property c As String
    Public Property d As String
    Public Property e As String
    Public Property f As String
    Public Property g As String
End Class
```

In my VB.net code, I am assigning a value to each property.

I want to send the **whole test class** as **one** parameter, and use all the values inside it.

So that if I add extra parameters later on, I want them to be used dynamically, instead of writing this everytime:

```
Textbox1.text= test.a & test.b & test.c .......
```

Any way to do this?

*Im not really writing the values in a textbox, but this is just an simplified example.*

Comment: Can you not pass it as a parameter to a method?  For example:  `Public Sub SomeMethod(t As test)`  And you can override the ToString method of your class to display or otherwise return the data from your properties as you need in one call.

Comment: What exactly is the use of this class? You might have a design issue.

Comment: @the_lotus I'm using it to store values of variables and so i wont have to pass them all as parameters every time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you want is a property. You'll need to add a property to your class like:

```
Public Property Combination() As String
    Get
        Return a & b & c & d & e ...
    End Get
End Property
```

Then to get the value you'd use

```
Textbox1.text = test.combination
```

(for more details you can see http://www.dotnetperls.com/property-vbnet)

Comment: That surely makes it easier to get all the values, but makes it tough to set values through code..

Comment: You can still use your properties a,b,c,d etc. in the normal way. It's just one additional property as well as your others and every time you call it you'll get the up to date combination of your other properties. Or do i misunderstand something?

Comment: and you'll only have to change the property in one place if you add more properties x,y,z to your class.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you override the built-in `ToString` function. Also, to further simplify this, add a `CType` operator.

```
Public Class test

    Public Property a As String
    Public Property b As String
    Public Property c As String
    Public Property d As String
    Public Property e As String
    Public Property f As String
    Public Property g As String

    Public Shared Widening Operator CType(obj As test) As String
        Return If((obj Is Nothing), Nothing, obj.ToString())
    End Operator

    Public Overrides Function ToString() As String
        Return String.Concat(Me.a, Me.b, Me.c, Me.d, Me.e, Me.f, Me.g)
    End Function

End Class
```

The you could just do:

```
Textbox1.text = test
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to dynamically get and set the value of properties on any object.  Such functionality in .NET is collectively referred to as *Reflection*.  For instance, to loop through all of the properties in an object, you could do something like this:

```
Public Function GetPropertyValues(o As Object) As String
    Dim builder As New StringBuilder()
    For Each i As PropertyInfo In o.GetType().GetProperties
        Dim value As Object = Nothing
        If i.CanRead Then
            value = i.GetValue(o)
        End If
        If value IsNot Nothing Then
            builder.Append(value.ToString())
        End If
    Next
    Return builder.ToString()
End Function
```

In the above example, it calls `i.GetValue` to get the value of the property, but you can also call `i.SetValue` to set the value of the property.  However, reflection is inefficient and, if used inappropriately, it can lead to brittle code.  As such, as a general rule, you should avoid using reflection as long as there is any other better way to do the same thing.  In other words, you should typically save reflection as a last resort.

Without more details, it's difficult to say for sure what other options would work well in your particular situation, but I strongly suspect that a better solution would be to use a `List` or `Dictionary`, for instance:

```
Dim myList As New List(Of String)()
myList.Add("first")
myList.Add("second")
myList.Add("third")
' ...
For Each i As String In myList
    Textbox1.Text &= i
Next
```

Or:

```
Dim myDictionary As New Dictionary(Of String, String)()
myDictionary("a") = "first"
myDictionary("b") = "first"
myDictionary("c") = "first"
' ...
For Each i As KeyValuePair(Of String, String) In myDictionary
    Textbox1.Text &= i.Value
Next
```